# Capsule manager table prefixes not being used

Tags: php, laravel

It's a Laravel website, just having a problem with table prefixes.

It has a MySQL table of static pages called `cleaning_pages` and in `public/index.php` I've put the following just before the `Kernel`'s instantiation:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule();
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'somehost.com',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'port' => 3306,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => 'cleaning_',
]);

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

I've given it the prefix `cleaning_` to save on having ugly class names. I then made a new Eloquent model class called `Page`, but then if I call it statically elsewhere like so:

```
public function fetchPage($slug)
{
    return \App\Models\Page::where('page_slug', '=', $slug)->get();
}
```

It throws a `QueryException`:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.pages' doesn't exist
```

But if, just purely for the sake of testing this, I put the following right in the `index.php` file right after the `$capsule` stuff from above:

```
print_r(\App\Models\Page::where('page_slug', '=', $slug)->get());
```

It queries the right table fine. I thought that the `Manager::setAsGlobal()` method was supposed to allow global static access throughout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a dumbass. I needed to set the 'prefix' in `config/database.php`, not just in the `Manager` instance. But this raises a further question - does the database config always override any `Manager` instance you make, even if you set it as global? Or am I not understanding this right?